# Criar banco de dados via linha de comando e sobrescrever existente

Tags: mysql, batch, cmd

Eu tenho uma function (Delphi) que cria processos e executa arquivos BAT que fazem,por exemplo, backup de um BD do MySQL, como este:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u root -proot BD > "C:\dbbackup.sql"
```

Existe uma linha de comando que eu possa criar o banco de dados no servidor, apenas o banco, para depois usar o SQL do backup e criar as tabelas populadas?Tipo assim:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -proot CREATE DATABASE BD
```

Depois eu usaria isso para popular:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u root -proot BD < "C:\dbbackup.sql"
```

A linha para criar a tabela não funciona.

**EDIÇÃO**

**Acabei descobrindo um erro de código ou sintaxe, segue o funcionando:**

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -
proot -e "CREATE DATABASE BD"
```

Porém como faço para sobrescrever o banco existente sem usar o "IF NOT EXISTS"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleta Database

Cria Database

```
Drop Database BD
Create Database BD
```

Comment: Eu pensava em uma unica linha, mas realmente depois de buscar informações é necessário dar o drop antes, então sua simples resposta está correta.